# Flutter: Sign up/Log in button not working nor storing in Firebase

Tags: flutter

I am a beginner and followed a video but now my signup/login page when pressed doesnt do anything. Doesnt take me to the home page nor even store the data in the firebase. Can i get some help, Thanks.

```
**authform.dart**

``import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class AuthForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const AuthForm({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AuthForm> createState() => _AuthFormState();
}

class _AuthFormState extends State<AuthForm> {
  void submitform(String email, String password, String username) {}

  //--------------------------------------
  final _formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  var _email = '';
  var _password = '';
  var _username = '`your text`';

  bool isloginPage = false;

  //--------------------------------shafinisstrugglin
  startauthentication() {
    final validity = _formkey.currentState?.validate();
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();

    if (validity!) {
      _formkey.currentState?.save();
      submitform(_email, _password, _username);
    }
  }

  //--------------------------------shafinisstrugglin
  //changed here
  submiform(String email, String password, String username) async {
    final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    UserCredential authResult;
    String? uid;
    try {
      if (isloginPage) {
        authResult = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: email, password: password);
      } else {
        authResult = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: email, password: password);
        uid = authResult.user?.uid;
      }
    } catch (err) {
      print(err);
    }

    // Use the uid to update the user's profile in Firestore.
    if (uid != null) {
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(uid).set({
        'username': username,
        'email': email,
      });
    }
  }
// to here_____________
  //--------------------------------shafinisstrugglin

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: ListView(children: [
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10, top: 10),
          child: Form(
              key: _formkey,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  if (!isloginPage)
                    TextFormField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                      key: ValueKey('username'),
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value!.isEmpty) {
                          return 'incorrect username bro';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      onSaved: (value) {
                        _username = value!;
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(3.0),
                              borderSide: new BorderSide()),
                          labelText: "Enter Username Bro",
                          labelStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins()),
                    ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    key: ValueKey('email'),
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value!.isEmpty || !value.contains('@')) {
                        return 'incorrect email bro';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    onSaved: (value) {
                      _email = value!;
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(3.0),
                            borderSide: new BorderSide()),
                        labelText: "Enter Email Bro",
                        labelStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins()),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    key: ValueKey('password'),
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value!.isEmpty) {
                        return 'incorrect pass bro';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    onSaved: (value) {
                      _password = value!;
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(3.0),
                            borderSide: new BorderSide()),
                        labelText: "Enter Pass Bro",
                        labelStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins()),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                      height: 70,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                          child: isloginPage ? Text('Log In') : Text('Sign Up'),
                          onPressed: () {
```

---

---

```
                            startauthentication();
                          })),
                  SizedBox(height: 10),
                  Container(
                    child: TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            isloginPage = !isloginPage;
                          });
                        },
                        child: isloginPage
                            ? Text('First be part of the fam?')
                            : Text('Already part of the fam?')),
                  )
                ],
              )),
        )
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Pubspec.yml

```
name: todofirebase
description: A new Flutter project.
publish_to: 'none'
version: 0.1.0

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.1.0 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_auth:
  cloud_firestore: 4.9.1
  firebase_core: ^2.15.1

  google_fonts:



dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

I tried to make a todo app and finished the signup/login page but after writing the code and tapping on the signup page keying in necessary details the signup page doesnt do anything nor store the data in the firebase.